Classify tubular neighborhoods under biholomorphic equivalence
I found a list of "open" problems in this article Finsler metrics of constant curvature and tube domains, where one of the problems said:

Classify under biholomorphic equivalence tubular neighborhoods of the zero section in the tangent bundle of complete Riemannian manifolds with nonnegative sectional curvature.

As far as I know, I only studied the "Tubular neighborhood theorem", but it doesn't concern anything about classifications, not to say "under biholomorphic equivalence".
Does anyone know some theorem about the classification of tubular neighborhoods and whether this problem is solved?
